# Intellij IDEA plugin how to get path of currently opened file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have already tried:

```
Document currentDoc = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor().getDocument()
VirtualFile currentFile = FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(currentDoc);
String fileName = currentFile.getPath();`
```

But that only gets the name of the file.

Comment: See this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000407770-How-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-a-VirtualFile- . Unless you're using LightVirtualFile, getPath should be working. If you are using LightVirtualFile, use PsiFile#getOriginalFile and then invoke getPath on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be happening because you're receiving a `LightVirtualFile`, which does not reside in memory. Try this:

```
PsiFile psiFile = PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(project).getPsiFile(currentDoc);
VirtualFile vFile = psiFile.getOriginalFile().getVirtualFile();
String path = vFile.getPath();
```

`getOriginalFile` returns a `PsiFile` object representing a physical file (or null if it's not in memory). If you are not sure the file is actually in your file system, check if the result of `getOriginalFile` is null first.

Refer to [this discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000407770-How-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-a-VirtualFile-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the file path from an event with the next code snippet:

```
var psiFile = e.getData(com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE)
val path= psiFile?.canonicalPath
```

The documentation of the DataKeys give us more information which information we could get:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/CommonDataKeys.java